# NEWBIE : Selecting 2 or more information from IEnumerable Select

Tags: select, ienumerable

Newbie here, I have a problem with my code. Before this code returns an array of string (student name) but I need to add the student id without requiring me to recode the entire method. Can someone help me on how to do it? Basically I need to include the Student ID based on the Student Name.

TIA.

```
public Student[] GetAllStudents(string subject)
    { 
        Student[] students = cache.GetAllStudents(subject);

        if (students == null)
        {
            Subjects group = RetrieveSubjects(subject);

            if (group != null)
            {
                students = group.Students.Select(r => r.StudentName).ToArray();
                // I need to include also the Student ID based on the Student Name queried above.

            }
            else
            {
                students = new string[0];
            }

            cache.AddAllStudents(subject, students);
        }

        return students;
    }
```

Comment: Is `Student` an alias for `string`? How does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use anonymous class in your select clause, ie

```
students = group.Students
                  .Select(r => new { name= r.StudentName, id= r.StudentID } )
                  .ToArray();
```

Or just select Student object as it should has all you need

```
students = group.Students.ToArray();

// doing .Select(r=>r) is redundant and can be omited
```

Seem that you need to create Student class from your studentinfo class, you would want to change prop's in initializer.

```
students = group.Students
                  .Select(r => new Student { 
                         StudentName= r.StudentName, 
                         StudentID= r.StudentID 
                   })
                  .ToArray();
```

Comment: @lc. I updated my answer actually, he doesnt seem to need select at all as he can use `Student` objects as he is returning array of it anyway.

Comment: thanks for your immediate reply. How can be my Student Class will be? right now here is my student class  public class Students
    {
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public int Studentid {get; set;}
    }

Comment: @Scuttle problem here is that we dont see signature of Subjects class. Can you update your question ?

Comment: Also what RetriveSubjects is intended to do ?

Comment: public class Students { public string Name {get; set;} public int Studentid {get; set;} }

Comment: th retrieve subjects just retrieve the subjects with students.. then I need to extract the student infos only.

Comment: why you need it if you already getting students by the subject?

Comment: @vittore - basically, the retrieve method gets the subject together with the students enrolled on that subeject. after the query, I need to extract only the Student Name and ID and return to calling method.

Comment: its a hierarchy. the calling method needs only the students for further processing

Comment: hmmm I tried but not. basically my original code retrieved the student name. the problem is theres another class studenttype that uses student info and it is wrapped in subject class.. sicne the subject class is the return type for Retrieve, I can't use the second snippet to retrieve the 2 columns. it says Students cannot implicitly convert to subjecttype type.

Comment: Noted.. sorry newbie here. :) thanks again... oh By the way.. can you help me on my other question?